# Problems running Java 8 TestNG inside IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I am writing a Maven application using OpenJDK 1.8 and running tests using TestNG.

When I run Maven from the command line everything works fine, but when I try to run the test inside IntelliJ, then the make process is displaying the following error:

```
java: javacTask: source release 8 requires target release 1.8
```

I have the project settings pointing to the 1.8 JDK and Project Language Level 8.

Inside Maven I have the following block (which I am guessing is not getting called yet as it seems to be the make causing the problem)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have even configured the Maven Runner JRE to point to the 1.8 JDK.

I just don't seem to be able to get IntelliJ 12.0.4 to run the tests properly

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you attach .idea directory and .iml files? You need to check that your modules do not override the bytecode level and all the modules are set to use JDK 1.8 with not extra compiler options added.

Comment: compiler.xml had     
<bytecodeTargetLevel>
   <module name="game" target="1.7" />
</bytecodeTargetLevel>

Can you write as an answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After the hint from [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder) it turns out that .idea/compiler.xml had the following section in it

```
<bytecodeTargetLevel> 
    <module name="game" target="1.7" /> 
</bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

I changed this to:

```
<bytecodeTargetLevel> 
    <module name="game" target="1.8" /> 
</bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

and it worked

Comment: This can also be changed in `Settings` → `Compiler` → `Java Compiler` → `Per-module bytecode version`.

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to make it. Go to Files->Other Settings->Type "javac" in the search bar -> change the JDK default to "1.8" or any version you target.

Comment: I didn't find 1.8 in drop down so had to change in .idea/compiler.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Xetius' answer didn't work for me in IntelliJ 14.1.2

In the end I found the section in `.idea/misc.xml`

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_6" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.7" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
   <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
</component>
```

I ended up with:

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" default="false" assert-keyword="true" jdk-15="true" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
</component>
```

Comment: FWIW, I think this is changed automatically after you switch the project-level JDK and intellij asks you if you want to reload the project. Strange that it wasn't done for you

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to go File > Project Structure > Modules. Half of my modules had their "module SDK" field set to the wrong thing (not Project Default as they should have been).